# Do TDS meters measure HCO₃⁻/CO₃²⁻?

Tags: aqueous-solution, ph, water-treatment

I am trying to add $\pu{2 g}$ of $\ce{KHCO3}$ to $\pu{20 L}$ of RO water $(\mathrm{pH} = 5.2)$ which theoretically it will add

$$
\begin{array}{lr}
\hline
\ce{K+} &\pu{10.32 ppm} \\
\ce{HCO3-} &\pu{16.1 ppm} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Will my TDS measure only the $\ce{K+}~(\pu{10-11 ppm})$ or it counts also $\ce{HCO3-}~(\pu{26-27 ppm})$ (or even $\ce{CO3^2-})?$

Comment: In my understanding, TDS meter estimation is based on conductivity measurement, so it takes into account all ions.